# Why do you need deep object comparison?

Tags: javascript, typescript, equality, deep-diff

reference: https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/

Following to the reference, deep comparison is:

> The deep equality is similar to the shallow equality, but with one difference. During the shallow check, if the compared properties are objects, a recursive shallow equality check is performed on these nested objects.

```js
const objA = {
  propA: 123
  propB: 'a'
  propObj1: { // assume reference: 1234
     propObj1: 'abc'
  }
}

const objB = {
  propA: 123
  propB: 'a'
  propObj1: { // assume reference: 1234
     propObj1: 'abc'
  }
}
```

Is it possible for `objA` and `objB` to be equal in shallow comparison but not in deep comparison?

Because their `propObj1` have the same reference, change to `objA.propObj1` will be also reflected to `objB.propObj1` which means they will also be equal in deep comparison. Can you give an example where it is `true` in shallow comparison but `false` in deep comparison?

Comment: "_their `propObj1` have the same reference_", they don't, both the properties are independent objects in the memory. If you create `propObj1` in `objB` like this: `propObj1: objA.propObj1`, then they would refer the same object.

Comment: It's *very* rare that you'd have what you describe here - two objects where the inner object property is shared. A lot of times this happens, it's because *it is a bug* - you've "cloned" the object but didn't realise it's a shallow clone. Yes, there are also cases where you *would* want the same object instead of a clone of it, however, that's rare. So, *in the scenario you describe* - no you don't need deep comparison. But 1. It's quite rare that you'd have it 2. You're also leaving out multiple nestings. Had you looked at *real* use-cases you wouldn't be asking this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your own question! The very fact that you had to say "assume reference: 1234" in your example says that you know that a shallow compare will not work if `propObj1` pointed to *distinct but equal* values (i.e. your **exact** example but without the "assume reference: 1234" comment.

`objA` and `objB` below will fail a shallow equals check, but pass a deep equals check:

```js
const objA = {
  propA: 123
  propB: 'a'
  propObj1: {
     propObj1: 'abc'
  }
}

const objB = {
  propA: 123
  propB: 'a'
  propObj1: {
     propObj1: 'abc'
  }
}
```